# Access NSMutableArray to an index with no value

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

if i try to access a nsmutableArray with objectAtIndex:x  and if i have no object at this index, my app always crash.

So my question is: how can i check, if there is something at this index, without crashing the app?

I hope your understand my question.
Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 5):

Check if your index is in array's bounds range:

```
   if (index >=0 && index < [myArray count])
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast reply. I know the method count, but i wanted to know if there is another solution to check if something is in an index at an array ;), Alex

Answer (score 1):

NSArray has a method called "count".
Call *count* on your mutable array and it will tell you the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are within the array's bounds, you will always have an object at a specific index between 0 and `[array count]`, as the array cannot have gaps of `nil` values in it.

Comment: You should never get a nil value from objectAtIndex: All elements of an NSArray are required to be non-nil.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: Use the `count` method to ensure you're within the bounds of the array, or catch the exception when you try to use `objectAtIndex:` Checking the range with count will be much lower overhead than catching the exception.

In case you didn't know - there are no "holes" allowed in an NSArray - the objects from index 0 to the end of the array ([`array count]-1`) will all be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(i=0; i< [myMutableArrayObject count]; i++) {
NSLog(@"%@",[[myMutableArrayObject objectAtIndex: i] myMethodDefined]);
}
```

Here, we are using a method predefined called **count** which returns the number of objects in the MutableArray Object
and then another method **objectAtIndex** which iterates the objects at the interval from 0 to (count – 1).

Regards,
Sumit